# Populate a dictionary with values randomly chosen from a list

Tags: python, dictionary

I have fixed keys in a dictionary representing seats and I want to populate the dictionary with values, randomly picked from a list (people).

Below I try, and fail, to choose randomly one element from the list people and place that element as a value in the dictionary d to key A1. Then move on and place the randomly picked element from the list people as a value to key A2.

If i was working with a dataframe I would use append at the end of the for loop. But append dosent work with dictionarys. Any ideas on how to proceed?

```
from random import randint

seats =['A1', 'A2', 'A3', 'A4']
people = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']

d = {k:None for k in seats}

while people:
    s = [people.pop(randint(0, len(people) - 1)) for _ in range(1)]
    for key in d:
        d[key] = s
```

Comment: So you want a dictionary with keys of `seats` and each key has a random element from `people`?

Comment: Why are you doing `for _ in range(1)`? You can just `[ ]` the code snippet.

Comment: For example `d = {seat: people.pop(randint(0, len(people) - 1)) for seat in seats}`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Problems are that your loop `for key in d` assigns the popped people to **every** key, you may not need that

---

That is way more simple than that, iterate and assign a rendom element that you pop out of the list

```
d = {}
for seat in seats:
    d[seat] = people.pop(randint(0, len(people) - 1))
```

Or pair the keys with shuffled list of peoples

```
from random import shuffle

shuffle(people)
d = dict(zip(seats, people))
```

Or even with `sample` to avoid modifying `people` list or copying it

```
from random import sample
d = dict(zip(seats, sample(people, k=len(people))))
```

Answer (score 1):

This is what comprehensions are for: To create new collections based on others.

```
from random import shuffle

seats =['A1', 'A2', 'A3', 'A4']
people = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']

shuffle(people)

d = {k:v for (k,v) in zip(seats,people)}
print(d)
```

Example output:

```
{'A1': 'B', 'A2': 'A', 'A3': 'D', 'A4': 'C'}
```

You want `seats` to be the keys of a `dict` and a random ordering of `people` to be corresponding values.

Answer (score 1):

```
import random

seats =['A1', 'A2', 'A3', 'A4']
people = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']

random.shuffle(people)
d = dict(zip(seats, people))
```